# how to check result set empty or not

Tags: jsp

i have a resultset. if result set is empty or null, then i want to set the value of "int b=0" in str16. And if the result set is not empty/find out something then execute the query. But i am facing some problem when the resultset is empty, then value is not setting in str16. What i did in my project is that after login i will show the total number of leave on employee profile if he took leave already. if employee did not take any leave then show 0 on the profile.

**checkleave.jsp**

```
     <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
     <%
       // storing the login id in abc becouse i have give table name as employee id 
      String abc= session.getAttribute("empid").toString();
      %>
      <%    
        try{
     int b=0;         
            Statement st=connection.createStatement();  

     ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select approcode,approemail,appromon,approvemon,approtue,approvetue,approwed,approvewed,approthr,approvethr,approfri,approvefri,approsat,approvesat,commen,months,SUM(nol) from `pushkalit`.`approval`WHERE (CONVERT( `approcode` USING utf8 ) LIKE '%"+abc+"%')");// here what i am doing  that if employee login then check in approval table where is approcode column as employee id if find something then execute table if column is not there then put value of b(i have declared int b=0) in str16. 

   if(rs !=null)       
   {  
     if (rs.isBeforeFirst() && rs.isAfterLast())  
      {  
       session.setAttribute("str16",b);
        }
        else
       {       
         while(rs.next())
        {  
          String str=rs.getString("approcode");
          String str1= rs.getString("approemail");
          String str2=rs.getString("appromon");
            String str3=rs.getString("approvemon");
          String str4=rs.getString("approtue"); 
          String str5=rs.getString("approvetue");
           String str6=rs.getString("approwed"); 
              String str7=rs.getString("approvewed");
              String str8=rs.getString("approthr");
              String str9=rs.getString("approvethr");
               String str10=rs.getString("approfri");
              String str11=rs.getString("approvefri");
            String str12=rs.getString("approsat");
           String str13=rs.getString("approvesat");
              String str14=rs.getString("commen");
             String str15=rs.getString("months");
             String str16=rs.getString(17);
            session.setAttribute("str16",str16);    
        }      
    }
    }
    else
    {
    session.setAttribute("str16",b);
    }

}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
 %>
```

but i am getting problem when employee login if column is empty then getting error.
this is empprofile.jsp.it will come after login. this code i have put in empprofile.jsp

```
<%
  String a = session.getAttribute("str16").toString();
 int y = Integer.parseInt(a);
 <tr><td><label>Total Leave Day:</label></td>
    <td><%=y %></td>
  %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check result set empty or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302097/how-to-check-result-set-empty-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

A resultset is empty if `rs.next()==false`.  So in your case, make a boolean, set it inside the while(rs.next()) loop, and check after the loop.

```
boolean blnResultSetIsEmpty = true;
while(rs.next())
{
   blnResultSetIsEmpty = false;
   ...
}
if(blnResultSetIsEmpty)
{
   out.print("There were no results");
}
```

Or, since your code is obviously only expecting ONE ROW, use an if-statement rather than while-loop:

```
if(rs.next())
{
   ...
}
else
{
   out.print("There were no results");
}
```

Comment: But i have to not print any things if result set have empty i have to put value 0 in session variable if result set have empty.

Comment: This is just the general idea.